# How do I configure eslint rules to ignore react-hooks/exhaustive-deps globally?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I have a react component with a useEffect hook that looks like this:

```
const LocationEditor: React.FC<SectionEditorProps> = (props) => {
const [section, setSection] = useState({...(props.section as Location)});
useEffect(() => {
    props.onChange(section);
}, [section]);
```

I'm getting this warning when I run the project:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' will change when *any* prop changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those specific props inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

So I tried changing the component to look like this, destructuring props:

```
const LocationEditor: React.FC<SectionEditorProps> = ({section, onClickCancel, onClickSave, onChange}) => {
    const [tmpSection, setSection] = useState({...(section as Location)});
    useEffect(() => {
        onChange(tmpSection);      
    }, [tmpSection]);
```

If I add this comment before the dependency array, I can make the warning go away:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

However, when I add the block below to `eslintConfig` in `package.json` it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "react-hooks"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off"
  }
}
```

I see some people talking about using the `.eslinrc` file, but I thought you could also configure rules globally in `package.json` and I can't find that file in my project.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: That is almost certainly a [bad idea](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/react-hooks-pitfalls). Just put the `onChange` function in your dependency array. Why is everybody's response to the tool, that *React team at Facebook itself uses*, telling them that they're possibly doing something wrong to immediately want to toss out the tool? I realize it's not just you, we get this question in the react tag all the time, it just never fails to surprise me...

Comment: Thanks!  That was helpful.  Basically I fixed it like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866796/understanding-the-react-hooks-exhaustive-deps-lint-rule

Comment: Acknowledging that it's a bad idea to disable this rule, it would still be nice to have an answer to this question for those of us who are stubborn. The linked answer does not address the problem of the package.json config seemingly being ignored.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot (ignoring warning): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63974832/how-to-disable-react-hooks-exhaustive-deps-eslint-warning-globally

Comment: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/removing-effect-dependencies#why-is-suppressing-the-dependency-linter-so-dangerous

Answer (score 25):

Usually you don't want to disable the rule. However, there are  few cases where it's worthwhile to disable it.

For example, if you're doing a fetch on mount and you're sure it never has to execute again, you can disable it with the code below.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

First, confirm the rule is wrong. It has been battle tested and most of the time it'll be right. You can introduce subtle bugs by ignoring the dependencies.

You can also disable the rule globally, although that's not recommended.

Comment: thanks!  Fixed it per the comment above.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: "Just do what the rule says" - it's not always the best option. An example: if you need to fetch data from a server, you usually pass to useEffect an empty array as a second argument (because you need to run the callback only once when your component did mount) - and it's an official advice from React documentation. And then "exhaustive-deps" often starts to annoy you with warnings that you "forgot" dependencies (but you're sure you didn't). And adding dependencies you don't need is an antipattern, because it may lead to unnecessary rerenderings or even to an infinite cycle of rerenderings...

Comment: This is just partly true, I think. Actually, the official documentation for useState says that it is safe to omit the setter from the dependency array.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate
Perhaps it is too much to expect from the linter to identify a setter or useReducer-dispatch function that is not included in the dependency array?