# "React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally." - How to ignore error for a whole file?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, electron

I have a React component that should only be displayed if the user are using the [Electron browser](https://www.electronjs.org/). Hence, I want to have an early return in my React component so I don't execute a lot of logic if the user is not using the Electron browser. I have the following minimal example:

```ts
export const MyComponent = () => {
    if (!isElectron) {
        return <p>You need to use Electron</p>
    }
    useEffect(() => {  // <-- gives error: React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.
        console.log("You are using Electron");
    }, []);
    return <p>You are using Electron</p>
}
```

The *useEffect* in the example above gives the error: `React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.` I simply want to ignore the error message for the whole file, and preferably not ignore other errors. How do I ignore the error message for a whole file?

Comment: Why not have the following check `if (!isElectron)` in the parent component which renders `MyComponent`? You cannot call hooks conditionally.

Comment: Just move that If condition below of useEffect and it will work.

Comment: @Maulik Patel, the code I've posted is a minimal example, in reality I've got lots of hooks below the early return statement and I don't want to execute lots of functionality if the user is not using an electron browser. That's why I would like to keep the early return statement on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the chance, then the solution posted by [@Giorgi Moniava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3963067/giorgi-moniava) is absolutely what you should be doing. If you are using [Eslint](https://eslint.org/) and Visual Studio Code, then you can add the following line to the top of a file to ignore all *rules-of-hooks* errors:

`/* eslint-disable react-hooks/rules-of-hooks */`.

Comment: I would not do that, the rules are there for a reason: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html. Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65704653/how-do-i-configure-eslint-rules-to-ignore-react-hooks-exhaustive-deps-globally

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is move that condition in the parent component, where you are rendering that component:

```
isElectron && <MyComponent/>
```

The error says that you are breaking one of the rules of hooks. So you can't do that.